# Hide only one side of the border with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide the left side of div element with javascript. I tried like following but it doesn't work.

I don't wanna use two different CSS class then change class name with javascript.

HTML

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black" id="myDiv">Div Element</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.border-left = "0";
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using `borderLeft`, as:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.borderLeft = "0";
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Where can I read the docs? I couldn't find on w3schools.com.

Comment: @MinNaingOo try avoiding w3schools reference, you could check in here:: http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javastyle.html or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style

Answer (score 2):

It's `borderLeft` property of DOM element.

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.borderLeft = "0px";
```

Example :
http://jsfiddle.net/6cVx3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style["border-left"] = "0";
```

Comment: @MinNaingOo it's working see it properly, it doesn't have left margin.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Nilesh it provides an answer.

Comment: @Mritunjay - It might. If you are asking somebody to try it doesn't really reflect confidence. You could have posted this as a comment on original post.

Comment: @Nilesh what a logic you've given, If you'll see many good answers they start with `try`, see the accepted answer of this post only.

Comment: @Mritunjay It seems flexible with CSS attribute so I don't have memorize or go to reference page to look. but I don't know why it doesn't work with Firefox 30. It worked well on Google Chrome.

Comment: @Mritunjay - I agree. Eat my words - you are right :-). Don't see a way to delete the comments though.